# total Sales count for last current week, month and yearly - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

How do you find the total sales count for a salesperson by weekly, monthly and yearly ?

```
  SELECT AdjusterName,    
   SUM(CASE WHEN TaskDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0)
            AND  TaskDate <  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()) + 1, 0)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WTD,
   sum(case when MONTH(TaskDate) = MONTH(GetDate()) then 1 else 0 end ) as MTD, 
   sum(case when year(TaskDate) = year(GetDate()) then 1 else 0 end ) as YTD

FROM   cte
GROUP BY AdjusterName
```

for example:-

```
  name         WTD      MTD     YTD

SalesPersnA   2        5       10
```

Sample Data

```
ID          SalesPerson    NAME                            TaskDate    TaskAge DocumentType                TaskStatus  OverdueCheck

2000378     Willy           Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1    2015-02-04  1258    Claim.Reassigned.File.Text  Completed   WithinSLA
2000378     Amanda          Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1    2015-02-04  1258    ClaimLifecycle.Open.RD.Text Completed   WithinSLA
2000388     Amanda          Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1    2016-08-06  709     ClaimLifecycle.Open.RD.Text Completed   WithinSLA
2000388     Willy           Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1    2016-08-06  709     Claim.Reassigned.File.Text  Completed   WithinSLA
2000388     Schutz          Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1    2016-09-21  663     ISO.Failure.Diary.Text:     Completed   WithinSLA
2000388     Stephannie      Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1    2016-09-26  658     Claim.Reassigned.File.Text  Completed   WithinSLA
```

Comment: [`COUNT` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Probably need to combine it with [`CASE` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). We can't really offer more details, as we don't have any.

Comment: You'll need to supply some actual sample data.  Otherwise `SELECT * FROM TABLE` from the data set provided.

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: included the query above, but not sure if I approached it correctly

Comment: I can't match the relationship about your sample data and expect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count` ignore `null`s, so you could use a `count` call on top of a `case` expression for the last week and month. The condition on the year could be expressed in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT   SalesPerson,
         COUNT(CASE DATEDIFF(WEEK,  TaskDate, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS WTD,
         COUNT(CASE DATEDIFF(MONTH, TaskDate, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS MTD,
         COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
WHERE    DATEDIFF(YEAR, TaskDate, GETDATE()) = 0
GROUP BY SalesPerson
```

Comment: getting this Incorrect syntax near '='. error after getdate()=0)

Comment: @BuddyCool hmm... forgot half the expression there. Don't know what came over me :-( Edited and fixed - try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want results for year, month, week in columns you can achieve with window functions:

```
declare @test table (ID int, SalesPerson nvarchar(100), [Name] nvarchar(100), TaskDate date, TaskAge int, DocumentType nvarchar(max), TaskStatus nvarchar(20), OverdueCheck nvarchar(20))

insert into @test values
  (2000378, 'Willy'     , 'Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1', '2015-02-04', 1258, 'Claim.Reassigned.File.Text ', 'Completed', 'WithinSLA')
, (2000378, 'Amanda'    , 'Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1', '2015-02-04', 1258, 'ClaimLifecycle.Open.RD.Text', 'Completed', 'WithinSLA')
, (2000388, 'Amanda'    , 'Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1', '2016-08-06', 709 , 'ClaimLifecycle.Open.RD.Text', 'Completed', 'WithinSLA')
, (2000388, 'Willy'     , 'Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1', '2016-08-06', 709 , 'Claim.Reassigned.File.Text ', 'Completed', 'WithinSLA')
, (2000388, 'Schutz'    , 'Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1', '2016-09-21', 663 , 'ISO.Failure.Diary.Text:    ', 'Completed', 'WithinSLA')
, (2000388, 'Stephannie', 'Akron FNOL Supervisor Team 1', '2016-09-26', 658 , 'Claim.Reassigned.File.Text ', 'Completed', 'WithinSLA')

select SalesPerson
    , Year(TaskDate) as [Year]
    , month(taskdate) as [Month]
    , DATEPART( wk, taskdate) as [Week]
    , count(*) over (Partition by salesperson, Year(taskdate)) as [YearCount]
    , count(*) over (Partition by salesperson, Year(taskdate), Month(taskdate)) as [MonthCount]
    , count(*) over (Partition by salesperson, Year(taskdate), DATEPART( wk, taskdate)) as [WeekCount]
from @test
```

Comment: Why would you year partition include month??

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me! Thank you all for your suggestions and time.

```
    select AdjusterName, NAME,
            sum(case when DATEPART( wk,TaskDate)  =  DATEPART ( wk, getdate()) and YEAR(taskDate) = 2018  then 1 else 0 end ) as WTD, 
            sum(case when DATEPART (m, TaskDate ) =  DATEPART ( m, getdate()) and YEAR(taskDate) = 2018  then 1 else 0 end ) as MTD, 
            sum(case when DATEPART (YEAR, TaskDate) =  DATEPART ( YEAR, getdate()) and YEAR(taskDate) = 2018  then 1 else 0 end ) as YTD

            from cte
            group by AdjusterName,NAME
```